# Android localization for any region some country

Tags: android, localization, locale, android-resources

I create folder values-ru (for any region). But with using Ukrainian language or Belarus i have an error.

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0d0037
```

Tell me, why i got an error. Does i must create values-ru-uk and etc. for all region?

Comment: post your code mate, it also occurs if you are trying to set the string value to INT

Comment: > "Does i must create values-ru-uk and etc. for all region?"
 Yes, you must

Comment: Sam, i use getString(R.string.some_text);

Answer (score 0):

You should define all your strings in the default (source) language, regardless of what translations you're adding.

These goes in: `values/strings.xml`.

If this is missing (or the string is missing in that file) then I expect that's why you get an error.

You can then add as many language files as you need:  e.g:

- `values-uk/strings.xml`. (Ukrainian)
- `values-be/strings.xml`. (Belarusian)

or specific regions thereof: e.g:

- `values-ru-rUA/strings.xml`. (Russian in Ukraine)

Disclaimer: I'm not an Android developer, but I've written localisation software that generates strings files.